# How reduce array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have got array of objects:

```
[
  {date: 'Mon', count: 5, ids: '3,7'},
  {date: 'Mon', count: 1, ids: '2'},
  {date: 'Thu', count: 4, ids: '16,23'},
  {date: 'Fri', count: 2, ids: '0,1'},
  {date: 'Fri', count: 2, ids: '8,9'},
]
```

And i want summ count for equal dates and get array of objects again. Expected output:

```
[
  {date: 'Mon', count: 6},
  {date: 'Thu', count: 4},
  {date: 'Fri', count: 4},
]
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First reduce your input array to group common dates and aggregate their count.

Then you can map over the object's entries to get the key value pairs as an array.

```js
const input = [
  {date: 'Mon', count: 5, ids: '3,7'},
  {date: 'Mon', count: 1, ids: '2'},
  {date: 'Thu', count: 4, ids: '16,23'},
  {date: 'Fri', count: 2, ids: '0,1'},
  {date: 'Fri', count: 2, ids: '8,9'},
];

const inputByDate = input.reduce((acc, { date, count }) => {
  if (date in acc) {
    acc[date] += count;
  } else {
    acc[date] = count;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.entries(inputByDate).map(([date, count]) => ({ date, count }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with an object as the accumulator.

```js
const arr = [
  {date: 'Mon', count: 5, ids: '3,7'},
  {date: 'Mon', count: 1, ids: '2'},
  {date: 'Thu', count: 4, ids: '16,23'},
  {date: 'Fri', count: 2, ids: '0,1'},
  {date: 'Fri', count: 2, ids: '8,9'},
];
const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {date, count})=>{
  (acc[date] ??= {date, count: 0}).count += count;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```